# Why is this query throwing an exception?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a `User` table that has a `BIT NULL` column called `NxEnabled`, and I can't change. Some of the records actually contain a `NULL` in that column.

I don't want to have a Nullable in C#, so it makes sense comparing it to true in the projection (the code is simplified, but this generates the same error):

```
context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == 4)
             .Select(x => new 
                  { 
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Name = x.Name,
                      Enabled = x.NxEnabled == true
                  });
```

Why does this query throw an

> InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type.`

when enumerated?

edit: Sorry for the typo. The query was actually more complex but the where clause is not the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compare `true` to your `.IsEnabled` field, LINQ to SQL passes the `true` as a parameter in the query. The problem with that is that the translation will return `NULL`:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name],
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[NxEnabled] = @p0 THEN 1
        WHEN NOT ([t0].[NxEnabled] = @p0) THEN 0
        ELSE NULL
     END) AS [Enabled]
FROM [Users] AS [t0]
```

Because of how SQL92 defines how comparing to NULL works, both `WHEN` conditions are false.
It is explained in this [this blog post](http://blog.istepaniuk.com/linq-to-sql-nullable-types-null-comparison/) [Disclaimer: the post is mine]

Use `Enabled = NxEnabled ?? false` instead as a work-around.

Comment: thanks! i had a the same problem for a long time. so weird that the c# expression has to take care of handling nulls like SQL in the select clause. i'll have to remember that

Answer (score 3):

Typo -- you need the double-equals `==`:

```
.Where(x => x.Id == 4)
```

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment to verify whether it it really is a typo or the source of the problem. The error message would imply not.

Comment: That couldn't possibly cause that exception

Answer (score 0):

```
context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == 4)
             .Select(x => new Users()
                  { 
                      Id = x.Id,
                      Name = x.Name,
                      NxEnabled = x.NxEnabled ?? false
                  });
```

Comment: Actually, to be equivalent to his code it would be `?? false`.  Since `null` is not equal to `true` it will result in `false`.

Comment: `?? null` is just pointless.  If it's `null` turn it into `null`?  You want `?? false`, as I said before.  This answer also lacks any explanation of why the OP's code doesn't work, because he actually has good reason to think that it should.

Comment: You've now changed it back to `?? true`, which is wrong, as I first said.

Comment: No, it is not correct.  It is now nullable when it shouldn't be.

Comment: @spajce, if i do that, NxEnabled will be of type `bool?` that is what i want to avoid.

Comment: i updated answer. i believe that was correct. try to test :)
and how to use the `??` operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx